# MongoDB server not starting up on local machine

Tags: database, mongodb

I have been trying to start the mongodb server on my local machine but it is NOT working. It used to work earlier without any errors. I am using macOS Big Sur.

I typed the following in my terminal. I have my mongodb database files setup in `mongodb-data` folder.

```
sudo mongod --dbpath “/Users/userName/mongodb-data”
```

but this is giving error and exiting with an exit code of 100. I have made sure `mongodb-data` folder is present.

Here is a snippet from the error log:

```
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"NonExistentPath: Data directory “/Users/userName/mongodb-data” not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."}}
```

The only change I have made is to replace my name by `userName` for privacy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe missing permission?

Comment: I have included "sudo"

Comment: I think you can block folder access even for root, however as root you can unblock it again by taking ownership (At least in Windows it works like that). Anyway, the error message is very clear. Maybe problem are the typographic quotes, `“` and `”`. Try simple quotes `"`, single quote `'` or no quotes at all.